# Get rid of Guard bundler warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, guard

How can I get rid of this warning (permanently)

```
Guard here! It looks like your project has a Gemfile, yet you are running
     `guard` outside of Bundler. If this is your intent, feel free to ignore this
     message. Otherwise, consider using `bundle exec guard` to ensure your
     dependencies are loaded correctly.
```

...without having to run `bundle exec guard` every time I launch it? I've worked on teams with more experienced test developers who've managed to get rid of this warning before, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guard checks if your current working directory contains a `Gemfile` and shows you the Bundler warning you want to get rid of. This warning has been added, because a lot of issues have been filed at the Guard issue tracker that are caused by a wrong `LOAD_PATH`, and running Guard with Bundler solves most of them.

If you use Guard in a project with a `Gemfile`, you should keep running Guard with Bundler, by either prefix Guard with `bundle exec` or use some binstub solution. I'm using a simple alias in my ZSH config `alias be=bundle exec` and I start Guard with `be guard`. If you prefer a binstub solution, I recommend to use [Rubygems bundler](https://github.com/mpapis/rubygems-bundler):

```
gem install rubygems-bundler
gem regenerate_binstubs
```

If you know what you're doing and don't want to see this message, you can use the `--no-bundler-warning` (or the short version `-B`). If you never, ever want to see this message again, create an alias `alias guard=guard -B`.

Comment: the gem solution is an interesting one